# Highlight cell red if empty under column name X in row name ABC on sheet 1, IF cell is TRUE under column name X in row ABC on sheet 2

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, lookup

I need help to highlight cell red if empty under column name X in row name ABC on sheet 1, IF cell is TRUE (ie. ticked) under column name X in row ABC on sheet 2.

I am ideally looking for a formula solution, not VBA if possible.

---

## **Scenario**

Example scenarios using the Google Sheet example I have linked below:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dcr0vWJdR8SWN8AJqPa7JJ1sRbu2bXDE_7YxLxs9fA0/edit?usp=sharing

I am referring to values in column A on both sheets as 'row names'
I am referring to values in row 1 on both sheets as 'column names'

**On Sheet 2 (Rules) **
for row name = "Brand123CatABC"

- Column Name "Attribute 1" value = TRUE (ticked)
- Column Name "Attribute 2" value = TRUE (ticked)
- Column Name "Attribute 3" value = TRUE (ticked)
- Column Name "Attribute 4" value = FALSE (unticked)
- Column Name "Attribute 5" value = TRUE (ticked)
- Column Name "Attribute 6" value = FALSE (unticked)

**On Sheet 1 (Products) **
for row name = "Brand123CatABC"

- Column Name "Attribute 1" value = "filled" (ie. not empty)
- Column Name "Attribute 2" value = EMPTY
- Column Name "Attribute 3" value = "filled" (ie. not empty)
- Column Name "Attribute 4" value = EMPTY
- Column Name "Attribute 5" value = EMPTY
- Column Name "Attribute 6" value = "filled" (ie. not empty)

---

## **Desired Outcome**

**On Sheet 1 (Products) **
for row name = "Brand123CatABC"

- Column Name "Attribute 1" cell should not be coloured as it is TRUE on sheet 2, but not empty on sheet 1
- Column Name "Attribute 2" cell should be coloured RED as it is TRUE on sheet 2 and it is empty on sheet 1
- Column Name "Attribute 3" cell should not be coloured as it is TRUE on sheet 2, but not empty on sheet 1
- Column Name "Attribute 4" cell should not be coloured as even though it is empty on sheet 1, as it is FALSE on sheet 2
- Column Name "Attribute 5" cell should be coloured RED as it is TRUE on sheet 2 and it is empty on sheet 1
- Column Name "Attribute 6" cell should not be coloured as it is TRUE on sheet 2, but not empty on sheet 1

Comment: Is the final implementation goin' to be *excel* OR *google-sheets* ?!

Comment: `Column Name "Attribute 6" cell should not be coloured as it is TRUE on sheet 2, but not empty on sheet 1` yet `Column Name "Attribute 6" value = FALSE (unticked)`. Please double check your Desired Outcome, Attribute 6 is inconsistent with the source data.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity: the rule appears to be that the Products Attribute should be coloured red IF: 1) the "Rules" attribute is FALSE (not checked) AND 2) the "Products" attribute is empty. a rather informal formula reflecting this would be: `=if(if(Rules1!D2=true,true,if(len('Products 1'!F2)<0,TRUE,FALSE))=FALSE,"colour red", "no colouring")`. Of course, this doesn't take into account the matching of values from one sheet to the other.